# Can I recursively get all by a foreign key in one row connected entries with SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on a speech recognition system. Those systems usually start with a base system. Then you get some more training data. Now you can adapt the base system to the training data. When you get more data, you can adapt the system that was already adapted. And so on.

The following image is a minimal example for the database that models the situation:

[image]

Now I would like to get a list of all traingdata that was used for one model.
I can do it with multiple selects. Here is some Python-like pseudocode:

```
def get_all_used_trainingdata(model_id):
    used_training_data = []
    based_on, trained_with = SELECT `based_on`, `trained_with` 
                               FROM models 
                               WHERE `id` = model_id
    used_training_data.append(trained_with)
    while based_on != Null:
        based_on, trained_with = SELECT `based_on`, `trained_with` 
                               FROM models 
                               WHERE `id` = model_id
        used_training_data.append(trained_with)
    return used_training_data
```

Is it possible to get this with one SQL Query? Is it possible to create a View for this?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using a recursive query.

As you didn't specify your DBMS this is ANSI SQL:

```
with recursive all_models as (
  select id, 
         based_on
  from models
  where id = 42 -- this defines the start of the recursion
  union all
  select c.id,
         c.based_on
  from models c
    join all_models p on p.id = c.based_on
) 
select * 
from all_models;
```

Recursive common table expressions are supported by all modern DBMS (this features was specified in the SQL Standard 2003)